# php html form submission is ignoring and continuing to post

Tags: javascript, php

I have this form which is submitting fine. The problem is i wanted to make sure a form field was not blank. Now when it is submited as being blank, it shows the error message next to "support1" form field. But it still posts to the database! Not sure why its ignoring and continuing onto the else statement.

```
<?php
$service_id = trim($_GET['srvid']);
$service_name = trim($_GET['srvname']);
$year = $_GET["year"];

$x="SELECT
nfw_week.week_no
FROM
nfw_week";

$xx= mysql_query("$x") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());     

// POSTING FORM WEEKLY ANALYSIS FORM START

$poster = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$support1error = "";
$support1 = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["support1"])) {
$support1error = "Name is required";
} else {
$support1 = ($_POST["support1"]);
$conn2 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$xplodedate = addslashes ($_POST['hiddenformfield']);
$xplodedatevar=explode(" ",$xplodedate);  
$weeknumvar=$xplodedatevar[0];
$datevar=$xplodedatevar[1];
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Melbourne");
$myDate = date('Y-m-d');
   $myTime = date('H:i:s');
   $take1 = addslashes ($_POST['take1']);
   $take2 = addslashes ($_POST['take2']);
   $take3 = addslashes ($_POST['take3']);
   $take4 = addslashes ($_POST['take4']);
   $take5 = addslashes ($_POST['take5']);
   $take6 = addslashes ($_POST['take6']);
   $take7 = addslashes ($_POST['take7']);
   $taketotal = addslashes ($_POST['taketotal']);
   $service_id = addslashes ($_POST['service_id']);
   $service_name = addslashes ($_POST['service_name']);
   $hours1 = addslashes ($_POST['hours1']);
   $hours2 = addslashes ($_POST['hours2']);
   $hours3 = addslashes ($_POST['hours3']);
   $hours4 = addslashes ($_POST['hours4']);
   $hours5 = addslashes ($_POST['hours5']);
   $hours6 = addslashes ($_POST['hours6']);
   $hours7 = addslashes ($_POST['hours7']);
   $hourstotal = addslashes ($_POST['hourstotal']);
   $wages1 = addslashes ($_POST['wages1']);
   $wages2 = addslashes ($_POST['wages2']);
   $wages3 = addslashes ($_POST['wages3']);
   $wages4 = addslashes ($_POST['wages4']);
   $wages5 = addslashes ($_POST['wages5']);
   $wages6 = addslashes ($_POST['wages6']);
   $wages7 = addslashes ($_POST['wages7']);
   $wagestotal = addslashes ($_POST['wagestotal']);
   $prospecting1 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting1']);
   $prospecting2 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting2']);
   $prospecting3 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting3']);
   $prospecting4 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting4']);
   $prospecting5 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting5']);
   $prospecting6 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting6']);
   $prospecting7 = addslashes ($_POST['prospecting7']);
   $prospectingtotal = addslashes ($_POST['prospectingtotal']);
   $weather1 = addslashes ($_POST['weather1']);
   $weather2 = addslashes ($_POST['weather2']);
   $weather3 = addslashes ($_POST['weather3']);
   $weather4 = addslashes ($_POST['weather4']);
   $weather5 = addslashes ($_POST['weather5']);
   $weather6 = addslashes ($_POST['weather6']);
   $weather7 = addslashes ($_POST['weather7']);
   $jobs1 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs1']);
   $jobs2 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs2']);
   $jobs3 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs3']);
   $jobs4 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs4']);
   $jobs5 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs5']);
   $jobs6 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs6']);
   $jobs7 = addslashes ($_POST['jobs7']);
   $jobstotal = addslashes ($_POST['jobstotal']);
   $support2 = addslashes ($_POST['support2']);
   $support3 = addslashes ($_POST['support3']);
   $support4 = addslashes ($_POST['support4']);
   $support5 = addslashes ($_POST['support5']);
   $weeklyyear = addslashes ($_POST['weekly_report_year']);
   $service_name1 = addslashes ($_POST['service_name']);
   $service_id1 = addslashes ($_POST['service_id']);
   //not doing anything with the below yet. needs to be added to the database as a row and the sql query
   //$paidfees = addslashes ($_POST['haveyoupaidfees']);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO nfw_weekly_report ".
       "(record_date, week_no, record_time, takings_sunday, takings_monday, takings_tuesday, takings_wednesday, takings_thursday, takings_friday, takings_saturday, takings_total,
        hours_sunday, hours_monday, hours_tuesday, hours_wednesday, hours_thursday, hours_friday, hours_saturday, hours_total,
        wages_sunday, wages_monday, wages_tuesday, wages_wednesday, wages_thursday, wages_friday, wages_saturday, wages_total,
        prospecting_sunday, prospecting_monday, prospecting_tuesday, prospecting_wednesday, prospecting_thursday, prospecting_friday, prospecting_saturday, prospecting_total,
        weather_sunday, weather_monday, weather_tuesday, weather_wednesday, weather_thursday, weather_friday, weather_saturday,
        jobs1, jobs2, jobs3, jobs4, jobs5, jobs6, jobs7, jobstotal,
        heardfromyn, byphone, inperson, byemail, rmfnotes, years, service_name, service_id)".

       "VALUES('$myDate','$weeknumvar','$myTime','$take1','$take2','$take3','$take4','$take5','$take6','$take7','$taketotal',
       '$hours1','$hours2','$hours3','$hours4','$hours5','$hours6','$hours7','$hourstotal',
       '$wages1','$wages2','$wages3','$wages4','$wages5','$wages6','$wages7','$wagestotal',
       '$prospecting1','$prospecting2','$prospecting3','$prospecting4','$prospecting5','$prospecting6','$prospecting7','$prospectingtotal',
       '$weather1','$weather2','$weather3','$weather4','$weather5','$weather6','$weather7',
       '$jobs1','$jobs2','$jobs3','$jobs4','$jobs5','$jobs6','$jobs7','$jobstotal',
       '$support1','$support2','$support3','$support4','$support5','$weeklyyear','$service_name1','$service_id1')";
mysql_select_db('ems_express');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql2, $conn2 ); 

// if the above is successful, display the popup modal with confirm of the invoice saved
echo "<script language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('#alertsaved3').modal('show');
       });
function OKClicked(){
        window.location='view-invoices.php?id=$cust_id'
        };
</script>";
};}
?>
<!--BEGIN PAGE WRAPPER-->
        <div id="page-wrapper" style=""><!--BEGIN PAGE HEADER & BREADCRUMB-->
            <div class="page-header-breadcrumb">
                <div class="page-heading hidden-xs"><h1 class="page-title">View Customers</h1></div>
                <ol class="breadcrumb page-breadcrumb">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;<a href="<? echo $siteurl ?>index2.php">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>Customers & Invoicing &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                    <li class="active">View Customers</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <!--END PAGE HEADER & BREADCRUMB-->
    <!--BEGIN CONTENT-->


    <div class="page-content">
<div class='row'>

                            <div class="portlet-body">
<div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="portlet">
                            <div class="portlet-header">
                                <div class="caption">Submit Weekly Analysis</div>
                                                           </div>
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                <div id="rootwizard-tabdetail">
                                    <div class="navbar">
                                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#tab1-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>1. Takings</span>

                                                    <p>Takings For Week</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab2-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>2. Hours Worked</span>

                                                    <p>The hours you worked</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab3-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>3. Wages</span>

                                                    <p>How much in wages</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab4-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>4. Prospecting</span>

                                                    <p>Hours spent prospecting</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab5-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>5. Weather</span>

                                                    <p>The Weather conditions</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab6-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>6. Jobs</span>

                                                    <p>How many jobs</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab7-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>7. Support</span>

                                                    <p>What support did you receive</p></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#tab8-rootwizard-tabdetail" data-toggle="tab"><span>8. Payments</span>

                                                    <p>Payments and final step</p></a></li>


                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="bar progress-bar"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div id="tab1-rootwizard-tabdetail" class="tab-pane">
                                            <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                                              <input type="hidden" name="service_name" id="service_name" value="<?php echo $service_name; ?>" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control"/>
                                              <input type="hidden" name="service_id" id="service_id" value="<?php echo $service_id; ?>" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control"/>
                                              <input id="week" type="hidden" value="">
                                              <div id="weekcommencing"></div>
                                                <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sunday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take1" id="take1" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Monday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take2" id="take2" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tuesday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take3" id="take3" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Wednesday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take4" id="take4" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Thursday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take5" id="take5" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Friday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take6" id="take6" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Saturday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="take7" id="take7" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Total Takings:</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i><input type="text" name="taketotal" id="taketotal" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control" readonly/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="tab2-rootwizard-tabdetail" class="tab-pane">
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sunday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" name="hours1" id="hours1" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Monday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" name="hours2" id="hours2" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tuesday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" name="hours3" id="hours3" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Wednesday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" name="hours4" id="hours4" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Thursday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" name="hours5" id="hours5" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Friday</label>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><input type="text" name="hours6" id="hours6" placeholder="0.00" onKeyUp="calcfunc_1()" class="form-control"/></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Saturday</label>
```

Comment: cant fit the rest in  :/

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` function; use MySQLi or PDO instead

Comment: Comment out everything in the script that is in the else block, and then do a var_dump or print_r on the $_POST array. Also, try to trim your question down to just the markup & PHP code necessary to test your conditional.

Comment: thanks Raptor, i didnt notice i had done that. i guess thats what i get for copy and paste. However that wont stop it doing what its doing now  :(

Comment: I would imagine it is happening because support1 is not empty. Have you echoed it to test?

Comment: it is definitely empty. i can see from firebug its empty in the post and also empty on echo. plus it returns the error message of a blank field. It just continues to post to the database. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isset()` to check whether the input exists, and use `empty()` to check whther the input is empty or not. For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['take5']) && !empty($_POST['take5'])) {
  $take5 = trim($_POST['take5']);
} else {
  // empty input, do something else
  // e.g. show error
}
```

Note: You probably need to escape the input for putting into SQL as well

Answer (score -1):

Use option `required="required"` on input fields that should be filled. Also, you can use `@$_POST['var']` to ignore those messages.

Comment: Never use `@` to suppress error / warning of empty input; it's not intended to do so. Also, `required="required"` is introduced in HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute); not applicable for older HTML / browsers.